# how to get php function return value in javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How can I use `return` a value from a PHP function to a JavaScript variable? Example:

PHP:

```
// Destination folder for downloaded files

$date = date('m.d.y'); 
mkdir("uploads/" . $date, 0777, true); 
$upload_folder = 'uploads/' . $date;

// If the browser supports sendAsBinary () can use the array $ _FILES
if(count($_FILES)>0) { 
    if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] , $upload_folder.'/'.$_FILES['upload']['name'] ) ) {
        echo 'done';
    }
    exit();
} else if(isset($_GET['up'])) {
    // If the browser does not support sendAsBinary ()
    if(isset($_GET['base64'])) {
        $content = base64_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    } else {
        $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
    }

    $headers = getallheaders();
    $headers = array_change_key_case($headers, CASE_UPPER);

    if(file_put_contents($upload_folder.'/'.$headers['UP-FILENAME'], $content)) {
        echo 'done';
    }
    exit();
}

$pathinfo = realpath($upload_folder);
return $pathinfo;
```

Javascript

```
this.MakeRequest = function()
{
  var somename = "somenameTest";
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET", "download.php", true); 
  xmlHttp.send();
}

function HandleResponse(response)
{
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = response;
      **var x = php return varible**

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function HandleResponse(response)
{
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = response;
      var x = <?php echo json_encode($pathinfo);?>; 

}
```

Comment: no it's not working, when i put this line to in my code thereafter my javascript not responding.

Comment: I added `;` to the end of php statement

Comment: this is my file structure,
index.php
css.css
uploader.php
dragdrop.js

index.php have only this JS
    if(window.attachEvent){
  window.attachEvent("onload",init);
  }else{
  window.addEventListener("load",init,false);
  } 
  var getInstance;
  function init(){
    getInstance = new uploader('drop', 'status', 'uploader.php', 'list');    
  }
  
   document.getElementById('test').onclick = function(){
     getInstance.MakeRequest();
   }

Answer (score 0):

Simply `echo` your `PHP` variable:

```
var x='<?php echo $pathinfo; ?>';
```

good luck!

Comment: not working, it's alert like this: <?php echo $pathinfo; ?>, not the pathinfo value